# Python: ujson print with newline

Tags: python, ujson

Trying to ujson.dump with newlines after every line, but I cannot seem to do it with the dump options (ujson doesn't seem to support the separators keyword).

Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Seems “indent” is the only formatting option.

Comment: Yes but my choices are either indent=0 where everything is on the same line, or indent=1 which puts every dict element on a new line, creating waay too much of a scrolling problem.

Comment: That's all you got. Your choice of tool makes other things not possible. If this is a real bother, why don't you just write a small python-Skript that you use to pipe the data through, which formats according to you wishes?